# User enters a text, in a prompt(); this text is saved in the browser, or changes the html file itself (preferred)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need help with the following functionality: User gives input with a text in a prompt();, which can have special characters, emojis, and etc in it. This input text, is saved or changes the html file code so that I don't have to rewrite this standard text every time.

I have just started in the programming world and have no experience with Javascript yet. Thank you in advance.

*EDIT*

I am creating a redirector for WhatsApp, the person enters the number, and when they click send, they are redirected to the whatsapp api, already with a message that is in a variable. I will share this code with other departments where people have no technical understanding to just change the html part of the message. This is where the problem comes in: when the user accesses the site for the first time, he gets a prompt();, through this prompt he inserts the default message, so that every time he sends a message without having to save the number in WhatsApp, he already sends it with the default message, and each department has its own message.

code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<script>




<!-- INFORMAÇÕES PARA A INSERÇÃO DA MENSAGEM PADRÃO

<!-- 1º Ao substituir o texto, verifique se possui as "aspas" entre a mensagem; -->
<!--2º Não adicionar caracteres especiais como: " ! @ # $ % ¨& * ( ) _ - + = : ; ; -->
<!--3º É possível a utilização de emojis; -->

-->




var mensagem = "REPLACE THIS TEXT WITH USER MESSAGE";



</script>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name= viewport content= width=device-width initial-scale=1.0>
   <title>Validação para WhatsApp - DPDF</title>
   <link rel="icon" href="http://131.72.220.28/forms-dpdf/crc/assets/img/logo.png">
   <style>
      img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      }
      body {
      margin: 0px;
      background-color: #0B7837;
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      }
      h1 {
      font-size: 1.8em;
      }
      p {
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-align: justify;
      }   

      #header {
         width: 100%;
         position: relative;
         background-color: #fff;
         display: flex;
         flex-wrap: wrap;
         justify-content: center;
         align-items: center;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      }
      
       #menu {
         padding: 0px;
         display: flex;
      }
      
      #menu li {
         margin-left: 10px;
         list-style: none;
      }
      
      #menu li a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #0B7837;
        display: block;
        padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1em;
      }
      
      #menu li a:hover {
        text-decoration: underline;
        color: #063b15;
   
      }

      #container {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      background: #0B7837;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center
      }
      #box {
      width: 70%;
      max-width: 600px;
      height: auto;
      background: #fff;
      box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      border-radius: 10px;
      padding: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      }
      #number {
      border-radius: 10px;
      border: 2px solid black;
      box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
      font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      text-align: center;
      width: auto;
      height: 40px;
      }
      #submit {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: green;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin-top: 25px;
      padding: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 1.1em;
      }
      #submit:hover {
      background-color: #00390B;
      }
      #rodape {
      display: flex;
      color: black;
      padding-top: 5px;
      justify-content: center;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 0.85em
      }
      </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav id="header">
         <ul id="menu">
           <li><a href="http://www.defensoria.df.gov.br/">Site da Defensoria</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://sei.df.gov.br/sip/login.php?sigla_orgao_sistema=GDF&sigla_sistema=SEI">SEI/GDF</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://cas.gdfnet.df.gov.br/owa/auth/logon.aspx?replaceCurrent=1&url=https%3a%2f%2fcas.gdfnet.df.gov.br%2fowa%2f">E-mail Institucional</a></li>
           <li><a href="https://pje.tjdft.jus.br/">PJE - TJDFT</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
   <div id="container">
      <div id="box">
         <img src="http://131.72.220.28/forms-dpdf/crc/assets/img/logo.png" alt="Logo da Defensoria Pública do Distrito Federal">
         <h1> Validador de WhatsApp</h1>
         <P>Forneça abaixo o número de telefone do Assistido para confirmar se o WhatsApp se encontra correto antes de enviar o formulário ao NAJ competente. </P>
         <form id="validacao"> 
            <input type="text" id="number" name="number" maxlength="15" required> <br/>
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Enviar">
         </form>      
      
 <!--  <footer>
    <div id="rodape">
        <p>2021 | Feito por Talles Reis dos Santos</p>
    </div>
   </footer> -->
   </div>
   </div>
   <script>
      var form = document.getElementById('validacao');
      var number = document.getElementById('number');
      
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
          
          // alerta o valor do campo
          //alert("Você será redirecionado para enviar a mensagem de confirmação para o WhatsApp " + number.value + ". Clique em 'Ok' para continuar e confirme se o Assistido a recebeu.");
          window.location="https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=55" + number.value + "&text=" + mensagem + "&app_absent=0";
      
          // impede o envio do form
          e.preventDefault();
      });
   </script>
    <script>
            // Máscaras ER
        function mascara(o,f){
            v_obj=o
            v_fun=f
            setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
        }
        function execmascara(){
            v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
        }
        function mtel(v){
            v=v.replace(/\D/g,""); // Remove tudo o que não é dígito
            v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); // Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
            v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2"); // Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
            return v;
        }
        function id( el ){
            return document.getElementById( el );
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            id('number').onkeyup = function(){
                mascara( this, mtel );
            }
        }
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, JavaScript can't write files. You'll need some server side stuff to do that.

Comment: show us what you got and where you're having trouble with your code and we can help out.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible with just JavaScript. The functionality you are trying to implement cannot be done because JavaScript is a client side scripting language, and it does not write into files.

Unlike JavaScript, PHP is a server side language, and it can do that.
For example, PHP function fopen() writes text files.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp

Or, there is a more advanced file_put_contents() function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php